# 58P01 ERROR: could not open file ".\src\main\resources\data\court.csv" for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a sql script that executes liquibase while running an application on the server. This script executes the command:

```
COPY court from E '\\ src \\ main \\ resources \\ data \\ court.csv' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I end up getting the error:
[58P01] ERROR: could not open file "\ src \ main \ resources \ data \ court.csv" for reading: No such file or directory.
Please give advice on how to set a relative path in my case?
I am working in Windows 10, Postgres.

Comment: ```COPY``` can only work with directories/files that the database server user(usually postgres) has permissions on. Does the postgres user have permissions on this director and or file?

Comment: Does the file path actually have all those spaces in it?